# When I add two integers it says invalid although supposedly it's for characters and symbols. Am I missing something?

Tags: c, calculator

In my calculator I tried firstly to make one operation functioning to have integers be displayed properly and when someone inputted a character it would say invalid.
When I input two integers it say's invalid. Not the actual sum of it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>  

int main(){

    char op;
    int num1, num2;
    int result;

    printf("Enter (+, -, /, *): ");
    scanf("%c", &op);

    printf("Enter Two Integers: \n");
    scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);

    switch (op){
    case '+':
    result = num1+num2;
    if(!(num1 == '+' && num2 == '+')){
        printf("Invalid");
    }
    else{
        printf("Sum: %d ", result);
    }
    
    break;

    case '-':
    result = num1-num2;
    printf("Difference: %d ", result);
    break;

    case '/':
    result = num1/num2;
    printf("Quotient: %d ", result);
    break;

    case '*':
    result = num1*num2;
    printf("Product: %d ", result);
    break;

    default:
    break;
    }

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I expected that with that new line of condition it will make characters and symbols print "Invalid"

Comment: What do you get if you output the input you scanned along with the return value of all uses of `scaf()`?

Comment: `num1 == '+'` makes no sense, since you read `num1` as an integer. It can't be anything other than an integer value. Otherwise `scanf` would have failed, which you don't check for. *Always* check what `scanf` (or any function in the `scanf` family) [***returns***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: What is even the check `if(!(num1 == '+' && num2 == '+'))` for? What problem is that supposed to solve?

Comment: Regarding the condition itself, unless you have entered the input `43` (ASCII encoded value for `'+'`) for both `num1` and `num2`, then `num1 == '+'` will be false, `num1 == '+' && num2 == '+'`  will be false, and `!(num1 == '+' && num2 == '+')` will be ***true***.

Comment: I get a nice sum output if I enter "+" and two totally random integers, like e.g. "43 43".

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude my first iteration for that was `if(!(result ==0))

Comment: On a totally different note: A condition like `!(result == 0)` is exactly the same as `result != 0`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!(num1 == '+' && num2 == '+'))
```

This doesn't make any sense for several reasons. First of all [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) and boolean algebra is often considered a prerequisite before studying any form of programming. By applying De Morgan/common sense, then we can tell that the opposite to "if num1 is + and num2 is +" is "if num1 isn't + OR num2 isn't +". That is:

`if(num1 != '+' || num2 != '+')` or if you will `if(!(num1 == '+' || num2 == '+'))`.

With that logic flaw out of the way, this is the wrong solution to the the actual problem anyway. You simply want to prevent the user from entering a character - any character not just `'+'` - when expecting a number. The easiest way of doing that is to check the result of `scanf` - it returns a number corresponding to the number of arguments successfully read. For example:

```c
int result; 
do
{
  result = scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2);
  if(result != 2)
  {
    printf("You must enter two numbers!\n");
  }
}
while(result != 2);
```

Another option is to read the input as a string with `fgets` and then parse that string afterwards.

---

As a side note, please note that `<conio.h>` has been obsolete for well over 20 years and if someone taught you to use it, you need a more updated source of learning. The future for freshly graduated MS DOS programmers isn't very promising...

Comment: My first iteration for that was actually if(!(result==0)) but it still prints invalid even though I inputted two integers.

Comment: unfortunately my school's curricular still use Turbo c/c++ as main compiler for c/c++... I didn't know sigh that's actually quite sad... But I used visual studio code to compile it. Thanks for telling me~~ @Lundin

Comment: @PipoyBagtas For students of computer archaeology: Since Turbo C and C++ releases there have been 2 major and 2 minor revisions of C, as well as 6 major revisions of C++. The original Turbo C went obsolete around 1995 with Windows 95 and a minor revision of C called C95. Turbo C definitely died in 1999 with ISO C99. The old Turbo BC++ 3.1 definitely died in 1998 during C++98 ISO standardization. It was _definitely not_ compliant with any standard version of C++. Various things called "Turbo" until Borland Builder 5-somewhere had shaky compatible with C++98 as well.

Comment: Although Visual Studio has a worse level of compliance than the ancient Turbo C, which at least conformed well to C90. Microsoft dropped support for C in favour for C++ some 20 years back, Their C compiler is a joke.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check the return value of `scanf` to ensure it read the number of values you expected.

`num1` and `num2` are `int` variables and you are reading into them using the `%d` specifier. If you type in `+` or other symbols, `scanf("%d %d", &num1, &num2)` will return `0`. A simple demonstration:

```
$ cat > testing.c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
  int op;
  int result = scanf("%d", &op);
  printf("%d\n", result);
}
$ gcc testing.c
$ ./a.out
+
0
$ ./a.out
67
1
```

The odds that `num1` and `num2` uninitialized both contain the value `'+'` are not impossible but *highly* unlikely, so the most likely outcome is that `"Invalid."` is printed.

As noted in comments, `43` is the ASCII code for `'+'` so if these specific numbers are input, both `num1` and `num2` will test as equal to `43` and their sum (`86`) will be printed.